# edge_index zero for all edges?

Tags: c++, boost-graph

Defining my `boost::graph` like the following, I get edge indices zero for all edges. Why? What am I doing wrong?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/graph/adjacency_list.hpp>

int main() {
    typedef boost::adjacency_list<boost::vecS, boost::vecS, boost::directedS, boost::no_property, boost::property<boost::edge_index_t, std::size_t> > Graph;
    typedef boost::graph_traits<Graph>::edge_descriptor Edge;

    Graph g(3);
    Edge e1 = boost::add_edge(0, 1, g).first;
    Edge e2 = boost::add_edge(1, 2, g).first;
    Edge e3 = boost::add_edge(2, 0, g).first;

    boost::property_map<Graph, boost::edge_index_t>::type eim = boost::get(boost::edge_index, g);
    size_t e1n = eim[e1],
           e2n = eim[e2],
           e3n = eim[e3];

    return 0;
}
```

As far as I can tell from documentation and examples, this should work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An adjacency_list doesn't have an **edge** index associated with it, only a **vertex** index. Which is quite logical once you think about how the graph is stored.

To have an edge index, you need to manually add it to the graph description, and then manually handle it.

Comment: Looking at [this example](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/libs/graph/doc/using_property_maps.html#sec:exterior-properties), they are using an `adjacency_list` with edge indices. Right? Or am I missing something?

Comment: @carlpett, notice that they have a `property<edge_index_t, std::size_t> >` which they manually assign in `add_edge(0, 1, 0, G);`

Comment: Then how to manually add it... It's too annoying that BGL library documentation is missing so much useful information.

Comment: @EmersonXu You pass it as a third argument when calling 
`add_edge(vertex1, vertex2, edge poperty, graph),` for example `add_edge(0, 1, 0, G)`.