# Boost Graph Library - weight property from external vector

Tags: c++, templates, boost, boost-graph

What am I doing wrong?

```
#include <vector>

#include <boost/graph/adjacency_list.hpp>
#include <boost/graph/dijkstra_shortest_paths.hpp>

using namespace std;

typedef boost::adjacency_list<> Graph;

void dijkstra(Graph &g, vector<double> &edge_weights, int source, vector<double> &dist,   vector<int> &prev) {
boost::dijkstra_shortest_paths(g, source,
                                 boost::weight_map(boost::make_iterator_property_map(edge_weights.begin(), get(boost::edge_index, g))));

}
```

(Compile with: **g++ main.cc -L/usr/local/boost/**)

Error:

> /usr/include/boost/graph/detail/adjacency_list.hpp:2665: error: invalid initialization of non-const reference of type ‘boost::detail::error_property_not_found&’ from a temporary of type ‘boost::detail::error_property_not_found’

I think the problem might be that there's no default mapping from edges to integers.  If so, how do I define one?

Comment: Please give a minimal complete file and compile line that reproduces this issue.

Comment: I've added the complete file as an edit.

Comment: Take a look at this: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_38_0/libs/graph/example/dijkstra-example.cpp

Comment: That example uses internal weights.  I want external.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your graph does not have an `edge_index` property, which you are using in your creation of the `iterator_property_map`.  You will need to add such a property to your graph and fill it in.  See [Boost Graph Library: Bundled Properties and iterating across edges](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7772400/boost-graph-library-bundled-properties-and-iterating-across-edges) and [edge_index zero for all edges?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7283128/edge-index-zero-for-all-edges) for what needs to be done.